# How-to bluetooth HID on android 4.2.2

Tags: bluetooth, android-ndk, android-4.2-jelly-bean, hid, bluez

I have an android 4.2.2 phone and bluetooth gamepad. I want to be able to interface with the gamepad using my custom app. That app is not for distribution, its only for my personal use. I could have used  [this app (called sixaxis controller)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscontroller) to interface with gamepad, but it requires, that Bluetooth must be turned off to operate, while I need an RFCOMM Bluetooth connection with another device in my app.

How can I have both requirements? I had tried [Sixaxis Compatibility Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscompatibilitychecker) and it works, so its possible somehow.

I tried to google for it, but did not found anything specific. There was a piece of advice to use NDK to interface with Bluez, that is base for Android BT API. On other side I found, that in Android Jelly Bean, Bluez was switched for Bluedroid, and its possible to build full custom android rom image with Bluez instead of Bluedroid.

I had an idea, that I could somehow compile Bluez for Android as library with NDK. Then I may put it in my app and use it. Is it right? If so, how can I do it?